# How to debug a webservice hosted by an IIS in a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, web-services, windows-7, silverlight-4.0, iis-7.5

Anybody knows how to debug a web service hosted by an IIS in a Silverlight 4.0 application?

My IIS version is 7.5 and my operating system is windows 7.

Can you please specify the steps on how to?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When running the solution (in debug mode, or have symbol files up-to-date).

1. Open the **Debug** menu then select **Attach to process**

   *(Or use shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)*
2. Find the process **w3wp.exe** || **WebDev.WebServerxx.EXE (Casini)**

   *(Check 'Show processes from all users' when working with IIS App Pool under other account)*
3. Click **attach**
4. Set breakpoint(s)
5. Do your debugging

Comment: +1 but just make sure that its attached for Managed code debugging.

Comment: Also make sure your web service was compiled in Debug mode, not Release mode (slapping forehead).

Comment: It's any way on Windows 10 (UAC is always on) and proccess is hidden?