# Debugging asmx web services

Tags: web-services, debugging, iis, asmx, attach-to-process

How can I debug asmx webservices running on IIS? I read that I must Attach to process called aspnet_wp or w3wp. But I can not find these processes... I selected checkbox show processes from all users but still nothing. What can be wrong?

regards

Comment: See this link for more info

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949193/how-to-debug-a-webservice-hosted-by-an-iis-in-a-silverlight-application

Answer (score 2):

If your service is not running, then there might not be a worker process running. Start your service by accessing it from the browser, of use "View In Browser" from inside of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be what you are looking for, but can't you run your project from visual studio first? I usually do it that way before going to IIS.

Or does your project run fine on VS and an other way with IIS? I personnaly never done it myself since I debug all my code in local.

As far as remote and local IIS debugging are concerned, I think you can check on this site [CodeProjectI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IISRemoteDebugging.aspx) and [CodeProjectII](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ProcessAttache.aspx). The author claims to be a former MVP in ASP.NET, should be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be logged onto the machine that runs web service. You would need a debugger installed on that machine.

If that is not possible, you can install remote debugger for VS on the server. To install remote debugger you just need to copy msvsmon.exe from your VS installation CD or from machine where VS is already installed and start it.

Then when you attach to proccess from your machine you can type in the name of your remote server and click Browse. You should be able to see all proccess that are running on remote server. You would need administrative or Debugger rights on that server.

Comment: I have VisualStudio 2008 installed on that machine.